# How to import 2 versions of a package in Python?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am currently having the library IPython version 5.5 for interface. I am planning to use one function, but unfortunately it has been removed from the library since version 2. As I cannot relegate my current IPython back to version 1 (since it would cause conflict with other library), is there anyway I could install 2 versions of IPython (by renaming one, like IPython_old)?

Comment: You'd use a virtual environment for something like this. Install one version of the library into one virtual environment, and another version into another environment. Also, in the future, don't rely on undocumented functions in libraries, since they can be removed without warning.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using a virtual environment with `venv` module. Using `venv` you could have different directories with different versions of every library you want. Here are the docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

And here is a good tutorial of how to really use this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk